# git lfs pull does not download lfs files on mac from bitbucket

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket, git-lfs

After entering `git lfs pull` outputs this

```
% git lfs pull
Downloading LFS objects:   0% (0/1), 0 B | 0 B/s
```

and nothing happens.

Repository located on bitbucket.

```
% git --version
git version 2.32.0 (Apple Git-132)
```

```
% git lfs --version
git-lfs/3.1.2 (GitHub; darwin amd64; go 1.17.6)
```

Also i tried `git lfs fetch` but there is the same problem

```
% git lfs fetch  
fetch: Fetching reference refs/heads/master
Downloading LFS objects:   0% (0/29088), 0 B | 0 B/s
```

I expecting downloading files

Comment: Set `GIT_TRACE=1` in your environment then rerun the command. It should show what's going on then.

Comment: UPDATE: fixed by downgrading `git-lfs` version to 2.13.3